# .NET Obfuscation vs. NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate my C#.NET application which uses Hibernate, but seemingly reflection does not work afterwards.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good obsfucation solution must have some way of disabling it for specific identifiers. This will typically involve adding attributes to certain methods/properties that you don't want to have renamed. The exact approach will depend on the obsfucation tool you're using.

**Update** for the tool you're using, [this forum post suggests](http://groups.google.com/group/eazfuscator-net/browse_thread/thread/ca4b55132863af88?fwc=1&pli=1) that it can be controlled through attributes.

Comment: I am currently using Eazfuscator.NET, but does not seem to have such option.